# Curangle() throwing this error - TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Tags: linux, python-3.x

Below is the original code:

```
    #Update the solar file for reporting
logsolar = open('/tools/inputs/solarvalues.txt','w')
writeline=("[myvars]\n")
logsolar.write(writeline)
writeline=("solar_heading: " + str(round((float(getsolarheading())),1)) + "\n")
logsolar.write(writeline)
writeline=("solar_elevation: " + str(round((float(getsolarangle())),1))+ "\n")
logsolar.write(writeline)
writeline=("actual_elevation: " + str(round((float(getcurangle())),1))+ "\n")
logsolar.write(writeline)
writeline=("actual_heading: " + str(round((float(getcurheading())),1))+ "\n")
logsolar.write(writeline)
logsolar.close()
```

The following is the error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solarrobot7-core.py", line 373, in <module>
    writeline=("actual_elevation: " + str(round((float(getcurangle())),1))+ "\n")
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

i've been through like seven pages of Google for this, but still can't figure out how to code this line so that it doesn't throw this error.  Sorry it took so long. The following is from where curangle() is first called.

```
#Read the IMU to get the angle of incline (forwards/backwards)
#This is what we use for the solar panels, so we have to switch
#from 0 degrees on the normal axis to 0 degrees on the horizon
def getcurangle():
    # The escape character for # is \x23 in hex
    serialport.write(b"\x23o0 \x23f")
    response = serialport.readline()
    words = response.split(b",")
    if len(words) > 2:
        try:
            if ((float(words[1]) -90) * -1) < 89:
                curangle = ((float(words[1]) -90) * -1)
            else:
                curangle = 0
        except:
            curangle = 999
        return curangle + AngleOffset
```

The "b" in .split(b",") was added to the original code to supposedly make this code run under Python-3.x.

Comment: What does `getcurangle()` return?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Chad S.  - Since this is not my program and i'm not a coder but am only trying to set this program up for a solar hot water heater, i'm getting all of these errors as i try to run it.  Part of the problem is that i'm trying to do this under Python 3.x.  i didn't discover until it was basically too late that the program was developed under Python 2.7 i think.  How should i determine what getcurangle() is?

Comment: Since the `str(round((float` (etc.) works on previous lines, this suggests that there is something about the value of `getcurangle()` that is the problem. Can you include that function?

Comment: Erica / sorry i took so long.  The code has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the exception, if response does not have a "," character to be split, then words[1] will not be filled and can't be converted to a float.
First check to make sure response contains a comma from serialpoint elsewhere in your code.

You can also check this by adding `print response` and then `print words[1]` to make sure words[1] is returning a number and not a null value.

With the except, we can assume that the return value is always an int (either words[1] is an int and is returned, or words[1] is not an int and 999 gets returned from the except) so the error is coming from AngleOffset.
Double check the value of AngleOffset.